# Gsheets to pandas df without Google API

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets

I am trying to a gsheet data into a pandas data frame without using Google API as follows

```
gsheetid = 'xxxx'
sheetname = 'xxxx'
gsheet_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={}".format(gsheetid,sheetname)
```

When I open the above URL, a csv file perfectly downloads but when I try to read this using pandas I get the following error

```
df = pd.read_csv(gsheet_url)
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2
```

I think this is because the csv file has ',' delimiter not only between values but within values as well.

Ex: Budget(Col name)=$80,000 or Team Members(Col name)Sam,Tom,Harry (all three present in the same cell of the gsheet)

If it is due to delimiter, how can I get around this? How to change to delimiter may be to "|" in the tq-Table Query? or Are there any other ways to achieve this?

[Sample Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cFlSvjHkQiSqmZk01q6ki0pH1ZwHmGJ9QYytBxOENO0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I thought that even when `$80,000` and `Sam,Tom,Harry` are included in the cells, no error occurs. Because when your endpoint is used, `$80,000` and `Sam,Tom,Harry` are returned as `"$80,000"` and `"Sam,Tom,Harry"`, respectively. So in order to correctly understand your issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike Sure hyperlinked sample data

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't open your sample Spreadsheet. I apologize for this. Can you confirm it again?

Comment: @Tanaike my apologies fixed it, please try again.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could open your sample Spreadsheet. When I tested your script using your sample Spreadsheet, no error occurs. The values can be correctly retrieved as the dataframe. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So can you provide the detail flow for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike it looks like the same file i created (which is based off original file) loads properly where the original is still having issues, I am trying to comb through the data to see if something is causing. Thank you so much for looking out, I will let you know my findings.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike I think you are smart & amazing and the matter of fact that you tried to help me out is a testament of it. The issue with the file is with sharing level, this code works if the gsheet is publicly shareable, which ofcourse my work file isn't. Need to figure out how to make it work for restricted access as well.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When your file is not shared publicly, it is required to use the access token. API key cannot be used for this situation. But from `am trying to a gsheet data into a pandas data frame without using Google API`, when you can use the access token, Sheets API can be also used. So I thought that in order to achieve your goal, it might be required to use a workaround. For this, I can propose to use Web Apps as a wrapper API as a workaround. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.